# Anyone interested in code golf?

Tags: discussion

I was happy to note today a chemistry-related post on [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196667/how-many-atoms-in-the-hydrocarbon):

> How many atoms in the hydrocarbon?
>
> A hydrocarbon is a chemical compound which consists of only hydrogen and carbon atoms. For this challenge, we will only consider the three simplest kinds of hydrocarbons: alkanes, alkenes, and alkynes with no branches.

The answers are, uhm, terse, eg:

> ćC•>·¿*•s÷θD>,₂I3(èH÷+·,

I realize this is more appropriate as a topic for a chatroom, but post here for others to pick up. Those who like to tinker with code and chemistry may take notice.

Comment: Yes, code. That is exactly how I would describe that answer...

Comment: Not to be all fun-hating here, but I think that would be too far off-topic on main site. As a chat room, why not?

Comment: @orthocresol Well, no reason this question has to stay up, I can delete it. What would be an appropriate chatroom to make this kind of announcement in?

Comment: Oh, sorry - I don't mean that the meta post is off-topic, it's perfectly fine! I just mean that code golf style questions would be off-topic on the main site.